# code version state - is there a consensus

Tags: version, semantic-versioning

In most open-source projects, I see that that a project version is made up from 3 numbers. Usually something like `VERSION_MAJOR.VERSION_MINOR.VERSION_MICRO`.

What would make sense to me is:

- `VERSION_MICRO` : a change in implementation only. i.e. linking against the new version won't produce compilation errors.
- `VERSION_MINOR` : a change in the public interface; minor deletions and adds. i.e. linking against the new version *will* produce compilation errors.
- `VERSION_MAJOR` : a change in how the library should be handled more generally.

Is there a widespread consensus on open-source (or closed-source) projects versioning ? Or something considered good practice ?

Answer (score 1):

Discover [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) at last